# How to prove that this inequality between real numbers holds

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

I have to prove that

> $$\frac{(x+y)^k}{2^k} \leq\max \left\{ {x^k,y^k}\right\} $$given that $\forall x,y>0$ and all $k\geq 1$

I have no idea how to approach this inequality.Please give me a hind i will try to solve my own.

Comment: Can you prove $$\frac{x+y}2\le\max(x,y)?$$

Comment: i will try @lord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x \leq \max \{x,y\}$ and $y \leq \max \{x,y\}$, so $x+y \leq 2\max \{x,y\}$. This implies $(x+y)^{k} \leq 2^{k}( \max \{x,y\})^{k}$. You can easily check that $(\max \{x,y\})^{k}$ is same as $\max \{x^{k},y^{k}\})$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x\leqslant y$, then $\max\{x^k,y^k\}=y^k$. On the other hand,$$\frac{(x+y)^k}{2^k}=\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)^k\leqslant y^k,$$since $\frac{x+y}2\leqslant y$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: i will try sir.

Comment: ok i have to do same thing for $x>y$?

Comment: Yes, that is what you should do.

Answer (score 2):

Expand $(x+y)^k$ and observe that the sum of coefficients are $2^k$.

Comment: it will be very complex  if k will be some irrational number

Comment: You Are right, it works only for rational ones.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Without loss of generality we can let $x\geq y$. So we just need $$\frac1{2^k}(x+y)^k\leq x^k\iff(x+y)^k\leq(2x)^k=(x+x)^k.$$
The rest should be obvious to you.