# $\frac{(x+y)^n}{2^n} \leq max \{x^n,y^n \}$.

Tags: inequality

How to prove that $\frac{(x+y)^k}{2^k}\leq max \{x^k,y^k\}$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$ and $x$ and $y$ are positive reals ?

I tried by Principle of Mathematical Induction.

It is clear for $k=1$. Let us assume that  it is true for $k=n$.

For $k=n+1$, we have $\frac{(x+y)^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}=max\{x^n,y^n\}\frac{x+y}{2}.$ Now I am stuck. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: The average of two numbers is less than or equal to the max of the two numbers. Prove this, then your claim follows immediately. Induction is not the way to go.

Comment: $\frac{(x+y)^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}\le \max(x^n,y^n) \frac{x+y}{2} \le \max(x^n,y^n)\max(x,y)=\max(x^{n+1},y^{n+1})$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3364213/42969

Comment: Actually, for positive $a,b$, we have $a\le b$ if and only if $a^n\le b^n$, so you only need to show that $\max(x^n,y^n)=(\max(x,y))^n$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that this inequality between real numbers holds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3364213/how-to-prove-that-this-inequality-between-real-numbers-holds) - from [Martin R's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703178/fracxyn2n-leq-max-xn-yn#comment9955114_4703178).